# How can I know if in jquery array present special value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.each(date_range, function(kr, time) {
    alert('time' + '=>' + time)
    alert(data_d.indexOf(time) != -1);
    if (time == timestamp) {

        data_d.push([timestamp, v.kreditbetrag]);
    } else {
        data_d.push([time, 0]);
    }
});
```

But I see every time in second alert false While I have same time in date_range Maybe because of the data_d array has in element pair of time and value. How can I know if time already present in data_d array?

```js
obj = {0:[kreditbetrag:1300,datum:'2018-03-30'],1:[kreditbetrag:2600,datum:'2018-03-29']};
date_range=[1521763200000, 1521849600000, 1521936000000, 1522022400000, 1522108800000, 1522195200000, 1522281600000, 1522368000000]
data_d=[];
$.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
$.each(value, function(k, v) {
  var timeStamp = function(str) {
    return new Date(str.replace(/^(\d{2}\-)(\d{2}\-)(\d{4})$/,
      '$2$1$3')).getTime();
  };
  timestamp = timeStamp(v.datum);
  

  $.each(date_range, function(kr, time) {
    alert(data_d.indexOf(time) != -1);
    if (time == timestamp) {
      data_d.push([timestamp, v.kreditbetrag]);
    } else {
      data_d.push([time, 0]);
    }

  });

});
});
console.log(data_d);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please share a working snippet that demonstrate your problem.

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: Use `<>` in your toolbar to create a snippet and try to replicate your problem here.

Comment: What is the value of `timestamp`?

Comment: 1521763200000   Foe example And it can reapets in data_d. But I need unique array element like data_d.push ([1521763200000,1300])

Comment: I'm sorry David, your code is unreadable with that much indention. Use a [beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) and make it readable. Also, do you know about `console.log` instead of `alert`?

Comment: I see that you are defining the timestamp function inside the loop... Why?

Comment: By the way, you are in for a nasty bug with your date processing, since the javascript date-object will give you a timestamp in the locale of the browser where it is running, that can have any timezone.

Comment: Please help me to edit the snippet There is an error I dont know why

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve? If not, please write in comment what you would like differently, and I will try to change that.

```js
obj = {
  0: {
    kreditbetrag: 1300,
    datum: '2018-03-30'
  },
  1: {
    kreditbetrag: 2600,
    datum: '2018-03-29'
  }
};

date_range = [1521763200000, 1521849600000, 1521936000000, 1522022400000, 1522108800000, 1522195200000, 1522281600000, 1522368000000];

data_d = [];

var timeStamp = function(str) {
  return new Date(str.replace(/^(\d{2}\-)(\d{2}\-)(\d{4})$/,
    '$2$1$3')).getTime();
};

$.each(obj, function(key, value) {
  timestamp = timeStamp(value.datum);

  $.each(date_range, function(kr, time) {
    if (time == timestamp) {
      data_d.push([timestamp, value.kreditbetrag]);
    } else {
      data_d.push([time, 0]);
    }
  });
});
console.log(data_d);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```